# How to provide hints to IntelliJ to exclude properties when using generate

Tags: intellij-idea

With IntelliJ 2016.2 is there a way to mark a property/method that should *not* be included when generation of code is done?

For example this class

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public void setFirstName(String firstName){ ... }
    public String getFirstName() { ... };

    public void setLastName(String firstName){ ... }
    public String getLastName() { ... };

    public String getFullName() { // returns first + last };
}
```

I would like to mark `getFullName` so it is not used when generating things like equals or toString since it is merely a connivence function.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a full answer, but when you generate equals/hashcode, the first screen has an option to select a template. Choose "..." and you can create your own new template for creating equals and hashcode. You might therefore be able to code something, eg reading an annotation on a field, that would allow you to exclude it from the generation.

These look suspiciously like Velocity macros to me but my understanding of them isn't good enough to take the solution any further.